# fish shell for loop oneliner

Tags: shell, fish

I'm not sure how to do a for loop using fish shell. I keep having to drop out of fish to run it in bash.

take this for example:

```
for i in $(cat subdomains); do curl $i | html2text >> websites
```

I get:

```
fish: $(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(cat)'.
for i in $(cat subdomains); do curl $i | html2text >> websites
         ^
```

Comment: fish is not compatible with bash or any other unix shell. It has its own syntax, which is [documented here](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html). Please do some research before asking a question next time

Answer (score 11):

```
for i in (cat subdomains); curl $i | html2text; end >> websites
```

is the answer